# Accessing the model from the viewcontrollers?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, model

I am creating an iPhone application, a game, and I am trying to understand and embrace the MVC architecture. I am planning to create a model, in this case called `HighScoresModel` that is responsible for holding all the information about high scores in my game.

1. Where should this model be created? In the AppDelegate? In the first view controller?
2. How should other view controllers access the model in order to pass messages like `addScore:withDifficulty:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option to to have a class method on `HighScoresModel` that will access a single, shared instance of the model from any object that needs it.

This is superior to the other options because no controller is responsible for instantiating the model, and the controllers are not unnecessarily coupled to the app delegate either.

As an example:

```
@interface HighScoresModel : NSObject

+ (HighScoresModel *)sharedHighScoresModel;
...

@end

@implementation HighScoresModel

static HighScoresModel *SharedHighScoresModel;

+ (HighScoresModel *)sharedHighScoresModel
{
    if (!SharedHighScoresModel)
    {
        SharedHighScoresModel = [[HighScoresModel alloc] init];
    }

    return SharedHighScoresModel;
}

...

@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, so basically a singleton? And is this generally accepted as an appropriate way to do these things? I ask because in the past I have used singletons and been told that they were a rather hackish way to do things.

Comment: Putting it in the app delegate is a singleton too - but just introduces coupling of all your code specifically to your application's delegate and reduces reusability and testability as well. I'm open to hearing other alternatives, or arguments that this is unacceptably hacky though, particularly when your high scores model must be accessed by multiple classes within the controller layer. But if only a single view controller needs it, and persistence can be accomplished during the lifecycle of the view controller, then having the controller instantiate it and retain it may be appropriate.

Comment: If this model needs to load data from file, where should that occur. Should I put that in the didFinishLaunching method of the AppDelegate?

Comment: That should probably be the responsibility of your `HighScoresModel` and likely go in its init method or any method that forces it to reload its data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Singleton and create the HighScoresModel in there.  The singleton will be accessible from all ViewController.

As far as other view controller passing messages you'll be able to do something similar from anywhere within the controller.

[MySingleTon myHighScoresModel] addScore:myScore withDifficulty:myDifficulty];

See the following link for more reference to singleton http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/