# How do I access a Model Object from different viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach to this, but I want to access my model for a Shopping Cart Class from different viewControllers. My first approach was to init a Cart * object in each viewController, but I think I just ended up with multiple cart objects when all I want is one that can be accessed globally. After searching I came up with a different approach that seems better, but no luck yet.

I have a button that is supposed to add a deal to a shopping cart.  but when I try to add it, the method is not getting called. Here is how I have it set up.

In my Cart class I have a NSMutableArray to hold my deals.

In my viewController I set up a property of type Cart *cart and initialized like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Cart *cart;
```

...

```
-(id)initWithModel:(Cart *)cart {
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        self.cart = cart;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Then my button method is this

```
-(IBAction)addDealToCart {

    NSLog(@"The Cart has %i items", [self.cart qtyOfItemsInCart]);

    NSLog(@"Added the Deal to the Cart");

    [self.cart addDealsToCart:self.deal];

    NSLog(@"The Cart now has %i items", [self.cart qtyOfItemsInCart]);

    self.deal.qtyInCart = self.deal.qtyInCart + 1;
    NSLog(@"the deal has %i items in the Cart", self.deal.qtyInCart);

}
```

In this line addDealsToCart:deal never gets called.

here is my addDealsToCart:deal method in my Cart Class

```
-(void)addDealsToCart:(Deals *)deal {
    [self.cartContents addObject:deal];
    NSLog(@"the deal was added to the cart %@",deal);
}
```

any help would be great. thanks

Comment: When you run your code does `NSLog(@"the deal was added to the cart %@",deal);` get printed? Same question for `NSLog(@"Added the Deal to the Cart");`?

Comment: @Barjavel no, `NSLog(@"the deal was added to the cart %@",deal);` does not get called.  This one does `NSLog(@"Added the Deal to the Cart");`

Comment: Seems like `self.cart` is probably `nil` then.

Answer (score 0):

Without going for a whole re-architecturing, why don't you pass your cart object to each view controller? I personally wouldn't go the singleton route that your description hints of.

Update (example):

```
UIViewController *yourNextVC = [[YourNextVC alloc] init];
yourNextVC.cart = self.cart //The current cart in your current vc, passing it along.
[self presentViewController:yourNextVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That looks good, I'll try it later tonight.. Would you init in the root view controller then?

Comment: Not sure where your cart comes into play with your app, but possibly early on (in one of your earlier vc's), or even the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method in your `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: Still though, not sure if this will help your `addDealsToCart` not being called. My suspicion is that you have multiple carts instantiated (or nil).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I really like your approach but couldn't get it work for some reason :( however, I found this and managed to get it working, So it looks like I'm going the singleton route for now (until more issues pop up).. Thanks anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168037/accessing-the-model-from-the-viewcontrollers

Answer (score 0):

I you just want one Cart variable througout the app you can have it in appDelegate if you want

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Cart *cart;
```

And taking out is simple

```
AppDelegate *appDelegateObject=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate];
appDelegateObject.cart.qtyOfItemsInCart= 1; //initialize where you want.
```

Take out in another view controller like this:

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegateObject=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate];
  NSLog(@"cart value: %d,appDelegateObject.cart.qtyOfItemsInCart);
```